# How can I tell my function to do something specific thing when it receives no parameters?

Tags: python, function, printing, parameters

So, I have the following function which should resemble the already implemented " print " function in Python. ( I know it is silly to make a function that only uses a pre-defined function but I am practicing with different things ) The thing that I want to do with my function is: make it act the same as the pre-defined one. That is, when the print function is called with no parameters, I would like it to print an empty line just as " print() " does. How do i do that ?

```
def print_str( string, how_many_times, tail ):
    print ( string * how_many_times, end = tail )
```

Comment: Make them optional? Set sensible defaults?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  could you please provide a link so that I can document for a bit ? I do not know what that would be

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` doesn't take a single string, it takes 0 or most strings as argument. `end` has a reasonable default. You can imagine a (simplified) definition of

```
def print(*args, end='\n'):
    ...
```

You need to do the same for yours. A reasonable default for `how_many_times` would be 1. If you don't want `print_str` to take multiple arguments, `""` would be a reasonable default for `string`.

```
def print_str(string="", how_many_times=1, tail='\n'):
    print(string * how_many_times, end=tail)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
def myfunc(a=None):
   if a == None:
      print()
   else:
      print("hi")
```

If no arguments are presented it prints nothing, but if an argument is given it prints `'hi'`.